# emerald --replace doesn't do anything

Tags: 11.04, compiz, emerald

I previously had emerald working with 11.04, as I had compiled from source. This morning, though, I updated a series of packages, and now emerald --replace doesn't work any longer. I know for a fact that it updated the kernel, but I can't seem to find a place where it will tell me what else it updated. (I blindly accepted updates, thinking that they were just minor).

At any rate, I recompiled emerald, and I ran it from the terminal to see if there is something that's going wrong, but when I run `emerald --replace`, it runs just fine, just doesn't change my theme when I select a new theme from the emerald theme manager. It does, however, report that it is `Reloading...` when I select a new theme - so it does seem to be running correctly.

Could it be there is something in conflict with it?

Comment: I've read that this PPA fixes emerald on natty - have you tried this?  https://launchpad.net/~malteworld/+archive/compiz

Comment: Are you using Unity?

Comment: Emerald isn't supported in Ubuntu.  Its quite possible that it will no longer operate.

Comment: @fossfreedom: Yes, I was using that, but then I was getting a segfault a while back, which caused me to build from source. That worked until this latest update.

Comment: @Roland: No, I'm using gnome-classic with the panel disabled and Docky + awn.

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix: I'm aware of that. However, I'm also aware that there isn't a replacement yet, so I'm hoping that I can keep my pretty windows until there is a replacement (I'm using the A-New-Hope theme, which is pretty sweet as it comes with an AWN and Docky theme as well). :) Can you recommend a better window decorator? I would be willing to switch.

Comment: @jwir3 In the question, it was mentioned that you could not find where a record of updates is kept. I just thought I'd mention you can open the Ubuntu Software Center, look under the History section in the sidebar and click the Updates tab to see a record of installed updates and when they were installed, in case that helps any.

Comment: @WarriorIng64: Awesome, thanks for that information!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You rebooted right? If so, use this tutorial: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/get-emerald-to-work-in-ubuntu-1104.html

Comment: Hm... I actually was unable to solve this problem. Apparently, emerald is a dead project. I'm a bit disappointed, because I liked the way my windows looked with emerald themes. Do you know of any projects that aren't dead and are like emerald?

Comment: What??? I thought that emerald was actively maintained. Well, I have no idea of any forks.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.